# "input type="submit"" not displaying as a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text-files, onsubmit

I am trying to create a web-based quiz application where the quiz is inputted through a form and then inputted into a text file. this will then be read from the text file to the user separately. My submit button is not working however, have i laid it out wrong?
The idea is to then read the text file line by line calling on values define by these lines, and displaying the options in radio format on a seperate webpage. Also, i wish to add a new button called "add question" which adds the question and 3 answer input texts to the bottom of the form, making it responsive to the user. Would i have to make the whole form a function and call on it?

```js
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

  set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  set s = fso.CreateTextFile(“using theseee / this.txt ", True);

      var year = document.getElementById(‘year’);
      var class = document.getElementById(‘class’);
      var topic = document.getElementById(‘topic’);
      var title = document.getElementById(‘title’);
      var question = document.getElementById(‘question’);
      var option1 = document.getElementById(‘answer1’);
      var option2 = document.getElementById(‘answer2’);
      var option3 = document.getElementById(‘answer3’);

      s.writeline(“Title: " + title);
        s.writeline(“Question: " + question);
          s.writeline(“Option1: " + answer1);
            s.writeline(“Option2: " + answer2);
              s.writeline(“Option3: " + answer3);

                s.writeline("-----------------------------"); s.Close();
              }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quiz Form</title>
  <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“TRYstyle.css”>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Quiz form</h3>

  <table>
    <form onSubmit=“WriteToFile(this.txt)”>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Title” name=“title” id=“title” maxlength=“200”/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Question</td>
        <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Question” name=“question” id=“question” maxlength=“200”/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Answer</td>
        <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Answer” name=“answer1” id=“answer1” maxlength=“200”/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Answer</td>
        <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Answer” name=“answer2” id=“answer2” maxlength=“200”/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Answer</td>
        <td><input type=“text” placeholder=“Answer” name=“answer3” id=“answer3” maxlength=“200”/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <input type=“submit” value=“Submit”>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid.

A form can't be a child of a table element, and an input can't be a child of a table row element.

Only table cells can be children of a table row.

Additionally, you can't use `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) to delimit attribute values. Only `"` (QUOTATION MARK) or `'` (APOSTROPHE ).

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

---

Aside: Once you solve that problem you will discover that `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is not made available to web browsers. You can't write to arbitrary files with browser-side JS.

Answer (score 0):

Your doublequotes are wrong.

This is how it is:

```
<input type=“submit” value=“Submit”>
```

This is how it needs to be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Because of that doublequotes, type is not recognised and by default input type is text. Thats why you are having that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You had multiple problems.

- First the use the correct quotes helps a lot of issues.
- Place your submit button in a td element so it won't be placed directly into a row.
- You used `class` as a variable name in your javascript which is not allowed.

```js
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    //No Idea what this is. Wont work in snippet
    //set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    //set s = fso.CreateTextFile(“using theseee / this.txt ", True);

    //use the correct quotes
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    //it's not allowed to use class as a variable
    var classEl = document.getElementById('class');
    var topic = document.getElementById('topic');
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var question = document.getElementById('question');
    var option1 = document.getElementById('answer1');
    var option2 = document.getElementById('answer2');
    var option3 = document.getElementById('answer3');

    //use the correct quotes
    console.log("Title: " + title);
    console.log("Question: " + question);
    console.log("Option1: " + answer1);
    console.log("Option2: " + answer2);
    console.log("Option3: " + answer3);
    console.log("-----------------------------"); s.Close();
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quiz Form</title>
  <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“TRYstyle.css”>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Quiz form</h3>

  <table>
    <form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this.txt)">
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" id="title" maxlength="200"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Question</td>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Question" name="question" id="question" maxlength="200"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Answer</td>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Answer" name="answer1" id="answer1" maxlength="200"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Answer</td>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Answer" name="answer2" id="answer2" maxlength="200"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Answer</td>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Answer" name="answer3" id="answer3" maxlength="200"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```